# NodeJS, Mongoose, Express: Check Database if User is New

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am using Mongoose with Express.

I want to check if a username is already taken.

```
var isNew = function(req, res, next) {
  if (User.find({ 'userData.name': { $exists: false } })) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
}
```

my Schema:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userData: {
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: String
  },
  imagePath: { type: String, required: true },
  notes: [ String ],
  contacts: [{
    name: String,
    notes: [ String ]
  }],
  locations: [ String ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will work assuming you are passing in json with a `name` attribute in the request body.

```
var isNew = function(req, res, next) {
  User.count({ 'userData.name': req.body.name.toLowerCase() }, 
    function (err, count) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      } else if (count) {
        return next();
      } else {
        res.redirect('/');
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. it works. I had to remove `imagePath: { type: String, required: true },` ... :)

Comment: Nice to hear, also since you are checking by `userData.name`, I would consider adding `lowercase: true` to the schema. This way you will not have 2 usernames that look like `userName` and `Username`. I edited the answer to account for this too. Another issue with the code I wrote is, that your app will crash if `req.body.name` is undefined. You should add a check for that too.